# Installing plugins/dependencies with Platform-Specific requirements using FlutterFlow?

Tags: flutterflow

I want to use a plugins/dependencies, and its installation steps require platform-specific changes to be able to work on different platform devices.

Example requried steps:

Android:

1. Add the following rules to your proguard-rules.pro file.
2. Use FlutterFragmentActivity instead of FlutterActivity in MainActivity.kt.
3. Requires Android Gradle plugin 8 and higher.
4. Use Kotlin version 1.5.0 and above.
5. Use Android 5.0 (API level 21) and above.

iOS:

1. You will also need to update in your Podfile platform: ios, '13.0'.
2. Add the following to your Info.plist:

can these changes be implemented through FlutterFlow to use that plugin? If yes, how?